# ID token lifetime should be matched with authentication cookie expiration when it's only 1 hour by default?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

The [ms docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) says:

> ID tokens shouldn't be used for authorization purposes. Access tokens are used for authorization.
>
> By default, an ID token is valid for one hour - after one hour, the client must acquire a new ID token.

**Isn't it contradictory**? Why would the client need to acquire new IdToken after it expires when it isn't used for authorization?

Further, the [ms docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configurable-token-lifetimes) says:

> Usually, a web application matches a user's session lifetime in the application to the > lifetime of the ID token issued for the user. You can adjust the lifetime of an ID token to control how often the web application expires the application session

So given the Id token lifetime is 1 hour by default, **does that mean I need to redirect user to identity provider each hour** (asp.net core blazor server app and Microsoft Identity Platform with AAD)?

Comment: Yes, that is the default but u can configure it . "A token lifetime policy is a type of policy object that contains token lifetime rules. This policy controls how long access, SAML, and ID tokens for this resource are considered valid. Token lifetime policies cannot be set for refresh and session tokens. If no policy is set, the system enforces the default lifetime value." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties) U have also there the defaults - ID tokens, SAML2 tokens: 1 hour

Comment: But it's not common behavior for web app to log in the user every hour (even when no user interaction is needed), is it? So how do they do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to share my idea here because it's a little bit long and adding a comment is not enough to have so many lines.

`Isn't it contradictory` -> In my humble opinion, it isn't contradictory, ID token for authentication(user sign in) and access token for authorization(user call api), this is how Azure AD designed.

`does that mean I need to redirect user to identity provider each hour` I'm also confused in this aspect and if someone knows a lot in this aspect, pls add here, I'm all ears. Normally speaking, in our web application, we might need users to sign in, and based on their own role, they should be allowed to access some of the websites but others are not allowed, and we have Azure Identity SDK to do all these things, let's see the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype) from Azure AD.

We are able to see that in these samples, we are not able to see the ID token, we use access token in the most of the scenarios. After we sign in the app, if we want to use SSO, AAD already enabled it, we don't need to do anything else. If we want to get the user profile, we could use graph API to get all the details rather than the claims inside the ID token. By the way, it also require additional code to get the ID token although it should [be returned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) after sign in successfully. But the sign in process is not controlled by us when we used the SDK. So here, it's hard for me to say when we need to use the ID token.

We also need to control how often we need our users to sign in again, here it looks like we need to take care of the lifetime of the ID token, but in my experience, but we also use access token, because access token will also expire, and if we need a new access token, we need to make sure the user is still "active" and if not, we still need the user to sign in again.

By the way, when we use microsoft identity platform, our app redirect to the microsoft sign in page to let users to use the microsoft account(user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com) to sign in. That means, if the user session in microsoft identity platform is still alive while the user session is  expired in local client, we would see the website redirect to sign in page and redirect back automatically...

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is designed to enable a session with APIs. The session lifetime is represented by the refresh token that renews short lived access tokens.

The ID token represents proof of the authentication event. A client validates it before accepting the token response from the authorization server. This is sometimes described as using an ID token to bootstrap a session.

For browser based apps it is also recommended to wrap such tokens into the latest secure cookies, as a partial protection against cross site scripting.

Some OAuth website technology stacks assume by default that your secure data is returned in HTML documents rather than by using the access token to call APIs. In such a context the ID token behaviour makes sense, otherwise it is indeed a little contradictory.

When using APIs, the short resolution is to configure the ID token to have the same lifetime as the refresh token. Ideally though, session expiry should occur when token refresh fails with an `invalid_grant` error code. My [example SPA](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final) uses cookie security and works like this.